# how is it possible that we can destructe an object using any property name in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, destructuring, object-destructuring

I have a doubt can any body help me with my doubt or can any one tell me where I can find my answer?

So as we know in object destructing we must use the same property name to destructure. However, in React when we destructure `useParams` from react-router-dom we use any random property name. example `const {randomName} = useParams()` is this not destructing?

By same property name I meant this:

```js
const person = { name: "jon", age: 32, location: "UK", }; 
const { name } = person; 
const { abc } = person; 
console.log(name); // logs - jon 
console.log(abc);// logs - undefined 
//(since we did not use the same property name as "name".
```

Comment: Yes, it is, but it only works if `randomName` was a property of the object that `useParams()` returns.  If it isn't, it doesn't work.  I'm not clear on your question.  What do mean "same property name"?

Comment: Thanks for the help, means a lot. By same property name I meant this:- const person = {
  name: "jon",
  age: 32,
  location: "UK",
};
const { name } = person;
const { abc } = person;
console.log(name); // logs - jon
console.log(abc);// logs - undefined (since we did not use the same property name as "name".

Comment: If you are looking to get all the params from useParams() with a random name, using deconstructing. You can use {...anyNameYouWant} = useParams() then you can use anyNameYouWant.map(param=>console.log(param))

The triple period is the spread operator.

Answer (score 1):

`useParams()` returns an object containing all the parameters defined in the URL; when you destructure that you're not using "any random property name", you use the parameters defined in the URL.

`const {randomName} = useParams()` will be undefined if `randomName` is not one of the URL parameters returned by `useParams()`.

Comment: `randomName` will actually be `undefined` not `null`

Comment: FWIW if you *did* want it to be null when the property doesn't exist then you can use `const { randomName = null } = useParams()`

Answer (score 0):

`const { name } = person;` is equivalent to `const name = person.name`. If `person` has no name `property`, `person.name` will as expected return `undefined` and so will `const { name } = person;`, too.